# Wireless doesn't work with Windows 7 and Lubuntu 12.04

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, wireless-networking, lubuntu

Today I installed Lubuntu 12.04 on my laptop in a new partition, next to Windows 7. After this installation both Lubuntu and Windows stopped being able to connect to WiFi. With the Ethernet cable connected to the router all is OK but neither OS is able to connect to wireless networks, even if it recognises the presence of the network.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: wat is the output of 1) sudo lshw -C network
2) rfkill list all

Comment: I formatted it again reinstalling win7, but the problem is still there and i can't use these commands. Do you think i should enter with ubuntu live and try to fix it in this way?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If it doesn't work with either operating system, it's likely a hardware problem.  By any chance did you happen to hit the disable switch?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Vostro 3500 and I solved executing those commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Worked for me