# Lubuntu on Thinkpad–Wireless

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, thinkpad, lubuntu

I have an old (IBM) Thinkpad T42. It was pretty much useless running XP, so I decided to install linux. I first tried Puppy Linux, but eventually settled on Lubuntu. I couldn't run 12.10 because it requires PAE, which is not available on the Pentium M. I am now running *only* Lubuntu 12.04 (I didn't partition it or anything; I don't have XP anymore).

Everything is working fine, except for the wireless internet — which is a pretty big problem for me. Under XP, the internet worked. It still worked under Puppy... but now it's not working. The thinkpad sees my network, but is unable to connect.

This post: [Wireless doesn't work with Windows 7 and Lubuntu 12.04](https://superuser.com/questions/508606/wireless-doesnt-work-with-windows-7-and-lubuntu-12-04)
is similar, but doesn't help.

`lshw -C network` tells me that I have a "Cisco Aironet Wireless 802.11b" interface, and
`rfkill list all` returns nothing...

On the network side: I have an dual band Apple Airport Extreme. Most of my [new] devices use the 5GHz signal, but the thinkpad is obviously seeing the 2.4GHz one.

Any help is appreciated — I would really like to get internet up on this computer.

Thanks!

Comment: Does Lubuntu have anything to do with the concept of a luser from the BOFH series?

Comment: I believe it comes from LXDE + Ubuntu

Comment: You might be best off getting an Intel mini-PCI card from eBay.  You might as get a wireless-G one, which will be faster (but make sure it is for your T42, as it has to be whitelisted in the BIOS).

Comment: Are you running the drivers through ndiswrapper or just whatever the system dubbed?

Comment: I don't have any drivers... I just realized that any drivers I may have had under XP/Puppy would have been erase when I formatted the HD :(.

Comment: From what I read they're in the kernel since 2.6, so you should be on them anyway. No worries.

Answer (score 1):

I am taking a look through the Ubuntu forums, and it seems to be a relatively common issue with that card, so I bet we can get you there.  Here is a well reviewed option:

> Add the following lines to your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist` file:
>   blacklist padlock_aes
>   blacklist geode_aes

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=826233&highlight=aironet)

Quite a few people have had success, so let me know.  If no-go, I will do more digging for you.

Comment: Further details on Linux support - http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Cisco_Aironet_Wireless_802.11b

Comment: Would that blacklist.conf?

Comment: If that's what's there, probably. Just note what you changed so you can roll back if anything negative comes as a result.